# Moving a number of files from a directory to another by conspicuous error

Tags: find, mv

So thanks to this site I've found the way to move all files from current date created on this date to another directory but there is an error which I don't understand:

```
Thu Aug 31; 15:05:02; marton;~/Свалени ;  $  find . -newermt 20170829 -not -newermt 20180101 -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /backup/desktop/books/Python/ML-demos/
mv: inter-device move failed: ‘.’ to ‘/backup/desktop/books/Python/ML-demos/.’; unable to remove target: Invalid argument
Thu Aug 31; 15:06:19; marton;~/Свалени ;  $
```

Is this problematic and how can I workaround this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because your `find` command finds `.`, the current working directory, and passes it to `mv`.

If you're just moving files (not directories), add `-type f` to the `find` command:

```
find . -type f ...(as before)...
```

This will filter out directories, including the `.` directory.

You may also get rid of `xargs` completely:

```
find . -type f -newermt 20170829 -not -newermt 20180101 \
    -exec mv -t /backup/desktop/books/Python/ML-demos/ {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to move `.`, which is the current directory. You can remove that by adding `-mindepth` to your `find` command. Try it first without piping to `xargs`, to see if you get the desired result.